# How do I resolve my two Git trees from different SVN migrations?

Tags: git, merge, tree, branch, git-svn

1. From svn to git but I just created new git repository without migrate with git svn... bad idea now I know...
2. Some work done in a new branch from this new repository without svn history...
3. Discovered git-svn and made a new branch svn-cloned with all the history from svn.

But now I have two trees, and GitHub tells me that I cannot pull my branch (some work done) from master (new without svn history) with this new branch migrated from svn...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- `<initial>` is the initial commit you made at step 1.
- all your further work in git is based on top of that and is pointed by master branch
- the git-svn'ed tree you want to integrate with is `svn/trunk`

you may simply do a rebase:

```
git rebase --onto <svn/trunk> <initial> master
#and if you wish to push your changes back to svn
git svn dcommit
```

alternatively and if you don't care about the history of `<initial>...master` you could do a soft branch reset.